# Check if 2 arrays have at least one element in common?

Tags: python, numpy

What's an easiest way to check whether or not 2 arrays have at least one element in common? Using numpy is possible, but not necessarily.

The code I've found so far only checks for the concrete common elements. Whereas I need only to check True or False condition.

Comment: Do the arrays have the same length?

Comment: sets would do the thing `bool(set(first) & set(second))` if you're okay with memory overhead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test if lists share any items in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170055/test-if-lists-share-any-items-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the input arrays to be `A` and `B`, you can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) with [`np.any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html), like so -

```
import numpy as np
np.in1d(A,B).any()
```

You can also use [`NumPy's broadcasting capability`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html), like so -

```
(A.ravel()[:,None] == B.ravel()).any()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `any`:

```
any(x in set(b) for x in a)
```

This is short to write but, as Jon has rightly pointed out it will create a new `set(b)` for each element at `a`, the following lines would avoid that:

```
sb = set(b)
any(x in sb for x in a)
```

Performance will improve if `b` is the largest array (compared to `a`):

```
(smaller,bigger) = sorted([a,b], key=len)
sbigger = set(bigger)
any(x in sbigger for x in smaller)
```

Comment: This will convert `b` to a `set` **each** loop... not very efficient

Comment: @JonClements Agree, better keep `set(b)` in a  variable.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with **sets**.

```
def doArraysIntersect(array1, array2):
    return bool(set(array1) & set(array2))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def lists_overlap(a, b):
    for i in a:
       if i in b:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

**In JavaScript**

```
const findCommon = (arr1, arr2) => {

     let set = new Set(arr1)
     arr2.forEach((item) => {
         if (set.has(item)) return true
     })
     return false
}
```

Basically, I've done what everybody has suggested here. In case, you're looking for a JS solution...