# How can I stop a for statement if one of them is true? Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to check if the list have something in common. If they have one print "x" but if they don't print "y". But only one of them, not both. Code:

```
lista_1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
lista_2 = [10, 12, 16, 5, 3, 2]
for i in lista_1:
    if i in lista_2:
        print ('Tienen un elemento en común')
        break
        exit()
    if i not in lista_2:
        print ('No tienen ningún elemento en común')
```

With this way it prints x once and y once, but I want to print only one of them

Comment: Can you please show what output you are expecting ?

Comment: I think this is just the wrong approach, with `set` operations or `any()`/`all()` you can do this much more efficiently

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if lists share any items in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170055/test-if-lists-share-any-items-in-python)

Comment: I've already read that question, but I don't want the same result as he does

Comment: @almartinez Well what result do you want then?

Comment: To show only once the result, the checking process I've already did it, with this I mean to not show the 2 prints, to first check and then print

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to iterate through the whole list before you can say that they have no elements in common, so I added a `for-else` statement.  Additionally, I made lista_2 a set to increase efficiency.

```
lista_1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
set_2 = {10, 12, 16, 5, 3, 2}
for i in lista_1:
    if i in set_2:
        print('Tienen un elemento en común')
        break
else:
    print('No tienen ningún elemento en común')
```

Comment: If you want this approach, then just use a `for-else` construct, no need for a flag, however, other approaches are better (see my comments on the question)

Comment: But even if they have something in common or not it prints no, why?

Comment: @almartinez I just tested it and that's not the case.  What input are you using?

Comment: @nfn neil I'm not using any input, the list are already defined

Comment: @Chris_Rands  Thanks for the input, I updated my code.  Never knew that existed, I'll make sure to start using that.

Comment: @almartinez code updated, run it through the new code.  It works.  I"m assuming that Tienen en elmento en comun means Has an element in common.

Comment: thats what i wanted. Thanks you very much, the answer is just to put the else out of the for.

Comment: Also you should make `lista_2` a `set`; this makes the membership testing O(l) rather than O(n), vastly improving speed on large datasets

Comment: @Chris_Rands  Updated.

Comment: Good, (last comment I promise), probably better to call it `seta_2` now

Comment: @Chris_Rands  Updated.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I don't think that every spanish word is an english word with a trailing `a` :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to check if 2 lists have common elements is to check intersection between the two:

```
common = list(set(lista_1).intersection(lista_2))
if(now common):
    print("no common elements")
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach would be to use:

`(list(set(lista_1) & set(lista_2)))`

This will take both lists, convert them to unordered sets that can then be compared between one another with the `&`  (and) operator. The result of this will be a set containing the items that match in both sets, which the outermost `list()` method will convert back into a list.

And if it's not empty, you've got matches. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do by looking at the intersection of the two corresponding sets:

```
 if set(lista_1) & set(lista_2):
    print('common elemens')
 else:
    print("no common elements")
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the process faster and more concise, you could use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set)  (*conjunto* in Spanish, I believe) for fast lookup, and use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to stop at the first found common element :

```
#encoding: utf-8

lista_1 = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
lista_2 = [10, 12, 16, 5, 3, 2]

conjunto_2 = set(lista_2)

comun = any(elemento_1 in conjunto_2 for elemento_1 in lista_1)

if comun:
    print('Tienen un elemento en común')
else:
    print ('No tienen ningún elemento en común')
```

Comment: @almartinez: Yes, it's been solved. My answer is more concise and possibly faster, though.

Answer (score -1):

If you code 2 `if`s, it will show both. You must use 1 `if` and 1 `elif`.
Change the second `if` to `elif` or `else`.