# Python 3 How to search children nodes of xml.etree.ElementTree for strings in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I want to make this simpler and be able to search a list of variables: alarm1,alarm2,alarm3... in alarmDict.values()

What I have so far that works:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 
tree = ET.parse (path.filename) #XML file 
root = tree.getroot()


for child in root:
    alarmDict = child.attrib      #This lists the alarm codes as dicts  
    if 'alarm1' in alarmDict.values(): print ('Contains this alarm', 'alarm1')
    if 'alarm2' in alarmDict.values(): print ('Contains this alarm', 'alarm2')
    if 'alarm3' in alarmDict.values(): print ('Contains this alarm', 'alarm3')
```

What I am going for:

```
for child in root:
    alarmDict = child.attrib      #This lists the alarm codes as dicts
    alarm_list = [alarm1, alarm2, alarm3]  
    if alarm_list in alarmDict.values(): print ('Contains this alarm', alarm_list[])
```

Comment: loop over `alarm_list` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another loop:

```
for child in root:
    alarmDict = child.attrib      #This lists the alarm codes as dicts
    alarm_list = [alarm1, alarm2, alarm3]  
    for alarm in alarm_list:
        if alarm in alarmDict.values():
            print('Contains this alarm', alarm)
```

If you want a really deep dive into the best way for checking list contents against another list, I'd recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17735466/4225229)

Comment: Worked perfect!  Thanks you!!