# Checking if a element of a set exists in another set

Tags: set, element, pyomo

Assume I got two pyomo sets A & B, which are containing following elements:

```
m.A = {1,2,3,4,5}
m.B = {a,b,c,d,5}
```

I want to check; if A has some elements which are also in B:

**EDIT:**

Well following **does not work**:

```
if m.A & m.B is not None:
    raise ValueError
```

At least for my case when `m.A = [None]` and `m.B = ['some_string']`, if-statement is also triggered, but `bool(m.A & m.B)` is working.

Comment: `if a & b` is what you want

Comment: will the intersection of these two sets work for you? "m.A & m.B" would give you elements which exist in both sets...

Comment: @npobedina I think you are right something like `if m.A & m.B == None:` would work.

Comment: The post https://stackoverflow.com/q/3170055/5270581 already answers your question.

Comment: Dupe starts with lists, not sets, but the answers are what you need.

Comment: @Icedkk if you need to raise an alert if there are common entries, then it's rather "if m.A & m.B => raise alert"

Comment: There is a bit of nuance here that makes this question similar, but not an exact duplicate of the usual Python question. The `Set` objects above are from the `Pyomo` algebraic modeling/optimization library, not standard python `set`, but due to duck typing, the behavior is the same in this instance. The usual `&` vs. `.intersection()` comparisons may not apply here.

Comment: @QiChen true. The odd behavior is that when I create the intersection of two sets via `m.A & m.B`, a virtual set is created without an element (it says `Virtual`, where usually the elements stay.) And this virtual set is triggering `if m.A & m.B is not None`.

Comment: This is lazy evaluation in action. The intersection set is not actually evaluated until it is used, so you are given a virtual set object back as a placeholder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most compact way you could achieve this is by using the **`&` operator**:

```
a = {1,2,3,4}
b = {4,5,6}
result = bool(a & b)
```

### Speed comparison

Using the `&` operator:

```
%timeit bool(a & b)
297 ns ± 3.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Using the `intersection` method:

```
%timeit bool(a.intersection(b))
365 ns ± 27.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

The two solution are pretty similar, the second one most probably faces overhead from the method call.

Comment: Well I ll try both, the only problem might me: they are no ordinary python lists therefore I am not sure if .intersection would work. or bool(). I ll try then update here.

Comment: These are method applied to sets, not lists. Bool casts the result to boolean, as it returns `False` for empty set `{}` and true for a non empty set `{something}`.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects):

```
>>> A = {1,2,3,4,5}
>>> B = {'a','b','c','d',5}
>>> A.intersection(B)
set([5])
```