# Python program that loops if user inputs particular word

Tags: python

I'm attempting to make a program that loops if the user inputs a particular phrase. Currently the program ends the loop no matter what the user inputs.

```
umlist = ['um', 'UM' , 'Um' ]
while True:
    phrase = input('Say something. ')
    umcheck=phrase.split()
    if umcheck in umlist:
        print("You said um, try again")
    else:
        break
print("Well done, you didn't say um.")
```

What do I need to change to have the program detect and loop if a user inputs "um"

Comment: with `if umcheck in umlist:`, you are checking if the whole list coming from `phrase.split()` is in `umlist`. you want to check each word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with a simpler solution:

Make your input lowercase, and then just check for 'um' in that:

```
while True:
    phrase = input('Say something. ')
    umcheck=phrase.lower().split()

    if 'um' in umcheck:
        print("You said um, try again")
    else:
        break
print("Well done, you didn't say um.")
```

Answer (score 2):

`in` looks for the occurrence of the `list` in the other `list`. It doesn't perform the intersection test as you think it does.

Just to illustrate, the only way you could make your condition match would be to put a list in a list, like this:

```
umlist = ['um', 'UM' , 'Um', ["my","sentence"] ]
umcheck = ["my","sentence"]
>>> umcheck in umlist
True
```

There are ways with `any` and other ([Test if lists share any items in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170055/test-if-lists-share-any-items-in-python)). My approach would be to work with `set`. Create a set of words you don't want to see, and see if the set of words the user inputted intersects:

```
umlist = {'um', 'UM' , 'Um' }
while True:
    phrase = input('Say something. ')
    umcheck=set(phrase.split())
    if not umcheck.isdisjoint(umlist):
        print("You said um, try again")
    else:
        break
print("Well done, you didn't say um.")
```

`umcheck.isdisjoint(umlist)` returns `True` if both sets have no element in common. Negate that for your test (or inverse the `if` branches for more clarity)

Answer (score 1):

At first, `umcheck` is a list! not a word.

exp:

```
phrase = "this is an um test"
```

then:

```
umcheck => ['this', 'is', 'an', 'um', 'test']
```

You can't find any list in `umlist`.

You can do this:

```
umlist = ['um', 'UM' , 'Um' ]
end = False
while True:
    phrase = input('Say something. ')
    umcheck=phrase.split()
    for item in umcheck:
        if item in umlist:
          print("You said um, try again")
        else:
          end = True
    if end:
        break
print("Well done, you didn't say um.")
```