# How to remove strings containing certain words from list FASTER

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension

There is a list of sentencens `sentences = ['Ask the swordsmith', 'He knows everything']`. The goal is to remove those sentences that a word from a wordlist `lexicon = ['word', 'every', 'thing']`. This can be achieved using the following list comprehension:

```
newlist = [sentence for sentence in sentences if not any(word in sentence.split(' ') for word in lexicon)]
```

Note that `if not word in sentence` is not a sufficient condition as it would also remove sentences that contain words in which a word from the lexicon is embedded, e.g. `word` is embedded in `swordsmith`, and `every` and `thing` are embedded in `everything`.

However, my list of sentences consists of 1.000.000 sentences and my lexicon of 200.000 words. Applying the list comprehension mentioned takes hours! Because of that, I'm looking for a faster method to remove strings from a list that contain words from another list. Any suggestions? Maybe using regex?

Comment: Make `lexicon` a `set` and reverse the search. There's no need to iterate the entire lexicon for each word in the sentence

Comment: could you post an answer with minimal working example? I'll compare the runtime to find the fastest solution

Comment: I'm on a phone so it's not very easy for me to do that. I might try but it's a lot of faffing and probably someone will answer before I manage it

Comment: I'm no Python expert but I can only assume that `sentence.split(' ')` is expensive since it creates an array for every single sentence. Also it would fail if a sentence has any level of punctuation such as a comma or period; so not only is it slow, it is incorrect. You could choose to turn each word into a regex such as `\bword\b` and apply it against each sentence using `re.sub()`. Not sure about performance but at least your logic would behave as prescribed.

Comment: @roganjosh. I'm on mobile, so didn't see your exchange with OP until after I posted :(

Comment: Apparently I was wrong anyways given that one of the answers presents a .2 second solution and it uses `.split()`. Good thing I prefaced with "I'm no Python expert" :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your lookup in a `set`. This makes it fast, and alleviates the containment issue because you only look for whole words in the lexicon.

```
lexicon = set(lexicon)
newlist = [s for s in sentences if not any(w in lexicon for w in s.split())]
```

This is pretty efficient because `w in lexicon` is an `O(1)` operation, and `any` short-circuits. The main issue is splitting your sentence into words properly. A regular expression is inevitably going to be slower than a customized solution, but may be the best choice, depending on how robust you want to be against punctuation and the like. For example:

```
lexicon = set(lexicon)
pattern = re.compile(r'\w+')
newlist = [s for s in sentences if not any(m.group() in lexicon for m in pattern.finditer(s))]
```

Comment: yeah, I figured that also out after exchange with roganjosh. Let you know the runtime in a sec

Comment: Thanks for writing it up :) upvoted. I'm not fussed about rep and glad my suggestion was enough to make you reconsider the approach, @hyhno01. It'll be orders of magnitude faster

Comment: runtime for len(lexicon) = 179.918 and len(sentences) = 241.564: 0.2079s. I'll keep the thread open a while to see whether there are faster solutions (although this is already really fast)

Comment: I've added some notes about how to do regex

Comment: I've removed my answer (as you were totally right > inefficient) and studied your answer. Worked a treat. Simple question. I noticed it is case sensitive. Any way to circumvent for future endevours? Do we have to upper everything for example or is there a text-compare parameter of some sort?

Comment: @JvdV. `lexicon = set(w.lower() for w in lexicon)` and `m.group().lower() in lexicon` or `w.lower in lexicon`, as necessary. Use `.casefold()` instead of `.lower()` if you want a more aggressive normalization than just lowercasing.

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize three things here:

<>Convert lexicon to `set` in order not to make `in` operation costless.

```
lexicon = set(lexicon)
```

<>Check intersection of `sentence` with `lexicon` in a most efficient way. It should use `set` operations. It was [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17735466/3044825) about performance of set intersection.

```
[x for x in sentences if set(x.split(' ')).isdisjoint(lexicon)]
```

<> Use `filter` instead of list comprehension.

```
list(filter(lambda x: set(x.split(' ')).isdisjoint(lexicon), sentences))
```

**Final code:**

```
lexicon = set(lexicon)
list(filter(lambda x: set(x.split(' ')).isdisjoint(lexicon), sentences))
```

**Results**

```
def removal_0(sentences, lexicon):
    lexicon = set(lexicon)
    pattern = re.compile(r'\w+')
    return [s for s in sentences if not any(m.group() in lexicon for m in pattern.finditer(s))]

def removal_1(sentences, lexicon):
    lexicon = set(lexicon)
    return [x for x in sentences if set(x.split(' ')).isdisjoint(lexicon)]

def removal_2(sentences, lexicon):
    lexicon = set(lexicon)
    return list(filter(lambda x: set(x.split(' ')).isdisjoint(lexicon), sentences))

%timeit removal_0(sentences, lexicon)
%timeit removal_1(sentences, lexicon)
%timeit removal_2(sentences, lexicon)

9.88 µs ± 219 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2.19 µs ± 55.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2.76 µs ± 53.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Note.** So it seems filter is little bit slower but I don't know reasons yet.

Comment: I'm dubious about your second claim. `any` will short-circuit so I think that would need to be run through `timeit` (it's certainly not intuitive to me that this will be a faster approach)

Comment: Can you check runtime?

Comment: Not at the moment because I'm on a mobile, but I think it's something you can check

Comment: ```AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute  'intersect'```

Comment: You're right. I have removed it as inefficient still and updated my current solution.

Comment: Can you add the timings? I'm curious

Comment: @ roganjosh Updated.

Comment: Thanks. I have a feeling that the sample size is too small to get a proper indication but I'll have to look tomorrow