# How to write DRY Python For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop, dry

I have a cannabis dataset that has a column for "Effects" and I'm trying to add a binary "nice_buds" column for strains that do not include certain effects. This is the code:

```py
nice_buds = []
undesired_effects = ["Sleepy", "Hungry", "Giggly", "Tingly", "Aroused", "Talkative"]

for row in sample["Effects"]:
    if "Sleepy" not in row and "Hungry" not in row and "Giggly" not in row and "Tingly" not in row and "Aroused" not in row and "Talkative" not in row:
        nice_buds.append(1)
    else:
        nice_buds.append(0)

sample["nice_buds"] = nice_buds
```

As of now, the `undesired_effects` list is doing nothing, and the code works perfectly fine in terms of giving me the desired output.

**My question though is if there is a more "Pythonic" or "DRY" way to go about this ...**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test if lists share any items in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170055/test-if-lists-share-any-items-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `all()` with a generator expression to simplify the if-statement

```
nice_buds = []
undesired_effects = ["Sleepy", "Hungry", "Giggly", "Tingly", "Aroused", "Talkative"]

for row in sample["Effects"]:
    if all(effect not in row for effect in undesired_effects):
        nice_buds.append(1)
    else:
        nice_buds.append(0)

sample["nice_buds"] = nice_buds
```

Or use `any()` & check for the presence of an effect:

```
nice_buds = []
undesired_effects = ["Sleepy", "Hungry", "Giggly", "Tingly", "Aroused", "Talkative"]

for row in sample["Effects"]:
    if any(effect in row for effect in undesired_effects):
        nice_buds.append(0)
    else:
        nice_buds.append(1)

sample["nice_buds"] = nice_buds
```

Answer (score 2):

### Given a dataframe `sample`

- Use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)
- Use [`pandas.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains)
- Strings have the potential to be upper or lowercase, so it's better to force one case, because Giggly != giggly
- `for row in sample["Effects"]` tells me you're using a dataframe. You should never use a `for-loop` to [iterate through a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758#55557758).

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create dataframe
data = {'Effects': ['I feel great', 'I feel sleepy', 'I fell hungry', 'I feel giggly', 'I feel tingly', 'I feel aroused', 'I feel talkative']}

sample = pd.DataFrame(data)

|    | Effects          |
|---:|:-----------------|
|  0 | I feel great     |
|  1 | I feel sleepy    |
|  2 | I fell hungry    |
|  3 | I feel giggly    |
|  4 | I feel tingly    |
|  5 | I feel aroused   |
|  6 | I feel talkative |

undesired_effects = ["Sleepy", "Hungry", "Giggly", "Tingly", "Aroused", "Talkative"]

# words should be 1 case for matching, lower in this instance
undesired_effects = [effect.lower() for effect in undesired_effects]

# values to match as string with | (or)
match_vals = '|'.join(undesired_effects)

# create the nice buds column
sample['nice buds'] = np.where(sample['Effects'].str.lower().str.contains(match_vals), 0, 1)
```

### `display(sample)`

```py
|    | Effects          |   nice buds |
|---:|:-----------------|------------:|
|  0 | I feel great     |           1 |
|  1 | I feel sleepy    |           0 |
|  2 | I fell hungry    |           0 |
|  3 | I feel giggly    |           0 |
|  4 | I feel tingly    |           0 |
|  5 | I feel aroused   |           0 |
|  6 | I feel talkative |           0 |
```