# Efficient way to find key by value in Python dict where dict values are iterables

Tags: python, dictionary, key, pairwise

I have an iterable of unique numbers:

```
lst = [14, 11, 8, 55]
```

where every value is somewhere among numbers of dict's iterable-values, say lists:

```
dict_itms.items() = dict_items([(1, [0, 1, 2, 3]), (2, [11, 14, 12]), (3, [30, 8, 42]), (4, [55, 6])])
```

I have to find each `lst` element in a dict such a way that, finally, I would have a list of keys pairwise against each element in lst.

This method:

```
keys_ = []
for a in lst:
    for k, v in dict_itms.items():
        if a in v:
            keys_ += [k]
            break
        else:
            continue
```

gives:
`[2, 2, 3, 4]`

Is there more efficient way to find every key pairwise against each number to find?

Comment: As I understood the question is to see if two lists shares any element(s). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17735466/2681662. This way you can get rid of one of loops (first looop)

Comment: all list numbers are unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean by 'efficient'; do you need this to be efficient in a *given* pass or in *aggregate*? The reason I ask is that typically the best way to handle this in aggregate is by doing a pre-processing pass that flips your key-value relation:

```
reverse_lookup = dict()
for k,v in d.items():
  for i in v:
    keys = reverse_lookup.get(i, [])  # Provide an empty list if this item not yet found
    keys.append(k)
    reverse_lookup[i] = keys
```

Now that you have your reverse lookup processed, you can use it in a straightforward manner:

```
result = [reverse_lookup.get(i) for i in lst]
# `result` is actually a list of lists, so as to allow duplicates. You will need to flatten it, or change the reverse lookup to ignore dupes.
```

The initial processing for the reverse lookup is `O(n*m)`, where `n*m` is the  total length of the original dictionary values summed. However, each lookup for the `lst` portion is `O(1)`, so if you squint and have enough lookups this is `O(p)`, where `p` is the length of `lst`. This will be wildly more efficient than other approaches if you have to do it a lot, and much less efficient if you're only ever passing over a given dictionary once.

Comment: Surely, efficient in aggregate, thanks, it is good idea to get the dict flipped at initial dict creation stage. As we are free to structure 2d data (presented in a dict here) as we like, what would your choice? I thought to compose 2d numpy array and use row index as a dict key here, but np.argwhere(np.isin(d, lst))[:,0] would not work on the ragged array.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `any` in a list comprehension:

```
print([k for k,v in dict_itms.items() if any(x in lst for x in v)])
```

Output:

```
[2, 3, 4]
```

###### Update

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17735466/13525512) `not set(v).isdisjoint(lst)` is the fastest:

```
print([k for k,v in dict_itms.items() if not set(v).isdisjoint(lst)])
```

Comment: thanks, but looks not as efficient

Comment: try replacing `any()` with `not set(v).isdisjoint(lst)`. is it much more efficient in your case?

Comment: I see, but it is required "to find every key against each number to find", i.e., there has to be a key in a list against  each value to find: len([2, 2, 3, 4]) == len(lst). This concerns Grismar's answer as well

Comment: Given those requirements I don't know how to further improve your solution.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and Pythonic implementation:

```
d = dict([(1, [0, 1, 2, 3]), (2, [11, 14, 12]), (3, [30, 8, 42]), (4, [55, 6])])

xs = [14, 11, 8, 55]

keys = [k for k, v in d.items() if set(v).intersection(xs)]
print(keys)
```

However, this doesn't duplicate the 2 key, which your example does - not sure if that's behaviour you need?

Comment: Looks better, thanks, more efficient , but not sure is it enough. Wait for some time