# Python function that takes two lists as input ,perform certain operations and return string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, loops

Function that takes two lists as input and checks for squares and cubes of elements in list1 are present in list2. It should return string if squares or cubes of all elements in list1 are present in list2.

```
def list_oper(list1,list2):

    square_nums = list(map(lambda x: x ** 2, list1))
    cube_nums = list(map(lambda x: x ** 3, list1))
 

    if (x in square_nums for x in list2):
      print("Squares are only present")

    elif(x in cube_nums for x in list2):
      print("Cubes are only present")

    else:
        print("No such pattern is present")
```

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    list1 = ast.literal_eval(input())
    list2 = ast.literal_eval(input())
    
    print(list_oper(list1,list2))
```

When I passed list1=[1,2,3,4] and list2=[1,8,27,64,100], it printed Squares are only present instead of cubes are present.

Comment: Maybe you want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/17735466/15032126.

Answer (score 1):

When we use a `elif` it only get executed all previous `if` and `elif` conditions do not satisfied. Therefore, let's code like this

```
pattern_exist=False
if (x in square_nums for x in list2):
  pattern_exist=True
  print("Squares are present")

if(x in cube_nums for x in list2):
  pattern_exist=True
  print("Cubes are present")

if (!pattern_exist):
    print("No such pattern is present")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `if` condition satisfied it simply terminate it will not run the block of `elif`.. you can convert into `if` condition.

You can see my another approach using `set()`

**Code:-**

```
def list_oper(list1,list2):

    square_nums = set(map(lambda x: x ** 2, list1))
    cube_nums = set(map(lambda x: x ** 3, list1))
    #print(square_nums)
    #print(cube_nums)
    if not square_nums.difference(set(list2)) and not cube_nums.difference(set(list2)):
        return "Squares and Cubes both are present"
    elif not square_nums.difference(set(list2)):
        return "Squares are only present"
    elif not cube_nums.difference(set(list2)):
        return "Cubes are only present"
    else:
        return "No such pattern present"
    

list1 = list(map(int,input("Enter the list1: ").split()))
list2 = list(map(int,input("Enter the list2: ").split()))
    
print(list_oper(list1,list2))
```

#Testcase 1 : when both cubes and squares are present

```
Enter the list1: 1 2 3
Enter the list2: 1 4 9 8 27
Squares and Cubes both are present
```

#Testcase 2: when square is present

```
Enter the list1: 1 2 3
Enter the list2: 1 4 9
Squares are only present
```

#Testcase 3: when cube are present

```
Enter the list1: 1 2 3
Enter the list2: 1 4 8 27
Cubes are only present
```

#Testcase 4: when no condition met!!

```
Enter the list1: 1 2 4
Enter the list2: 1 4 9
No such pattern present
```

Comment: This is not correct, if `square_nums` is exist and `cude_nums` do not exists, then `"No such pattern is present"` this gets printed.

Comment: yeah you are right just updated with some testcases also..!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, `1 ** 2 == 1`
if you want to print when only all matched list,

```
if all(x in square_nums for x in list2):
  print("Squares are only present")
```

elif statement too.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
elif(x in cube_nums for x in list2):
  print("Cubes are only present")
```

Change the elif into if, and also change the else aswell.

Comment: This is not correct, if square_nums is exist and cude_nums do not exists, then "No such pattern is present" this gets printed.