# comparing two lists, python

Tags: python, nested, for-loop

I should define a function overlapping() that takes two lists and returns True if they have at least one member in common, False otherwise. For the sake of the exercise, I should write it using two nested for-loops. What am I doing wrong?

```
def overlapping(a,b):
    for char in a:
        for char2 in b:
            return char in char2
```

Any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: See [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197482/efficiently-knowing-if-intersection-of-two-list-is-empty-or-not-in-python/2215556#2215556) answer for ideas. It is possible that you and Manuel had the same course and/or teacher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to use 2 loops:

```
def overlapping(a,b):
    for char1 in a:
        for char2 in b:
            if char1 == char2: return True
    return False
```

But the solution with sets is much better.

Comment: This one works fine! Thanks.
The set() is good too but since the nested for-loops are required I cant't use set()

Answer (score 2):

You should use `==` and not the `in` operator

```
def overlapping(list_a,list_b):
    for char_in_list_a in list_a:
        for char_in_list_b in list_b:
            if char_in_list_a == char_in_list_b:
                return True
    return False
```

If you want something using set:

```
def overlapping(a,b):
         return bool(set(a) & set(b))
```

Comment: The one I'd go with if it was my code, but sadly the assignment requires nested loops.

Comment: This is going to return True only if a[0] == b[0] and False in every other case.

Comment: First code is completely wrong, second is basically a complete solution to a HOMEWORK task. And is wrong too, since Gusto is asked to provide a solution with two nested for-loops.

Comment: @raceCh For me it's irrelevant that is a Homework task. I just answer questions. For further reading, have a look at this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @systempuntoout which doesn't change the fact that both are wrong: first one contains unneeded else in improper place, second is not really answer to the question.

Comment: @systempuntoout I removed the downvote, since now it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Return ends the function immediately when executed. Since this is a homework, you should figure working solution by yourself. You might consider using a set.